# How to subtract inner array value from outer array value?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following `test.json` file:

```
{
    "now": 1685613599.879,
    "messages": 1347296469,
    "aircraft": [
      {
        "hex": "7c806e",
        "type": "adsc",
        "flight": "QF94    ",
        "r": "VH-ZNK",
        "t": "B789",
        "alt_baro": 34000,
        "gs": 475.0,
        "track": 231.55,
        "lat": 12.694702,
        "lon": -146.525860,
        "nic": 0,
        "rc": 0,
        "seen_pos": 24.752,
        "alert": 0,
        "spi": 0,
        "mlat": [],
        "tisb": [],
        "messages": 6145890,
        "seen": 24.8,
        "rssi": -49.5
      },
      {
        "hex": "3c4dc5",
        "type": "adsb_icao",
        "flight": "DLH9LL  ",
        "r": "D-ACNE",
        "t": "CRJ9",
        "alt_baro": 5250,
        "gs": 253.3,
        "track": 182.72,
        "lat": 49.848068,
        "lon": 7.385010,
        "nic": 8,
        "rc": 186,
        "seen_pos": 0.180,
        "alert": 0,
        "spi": 0,
        "mlat": [],
        "tisb": [],
        "messages": 9278490,
        "seen": 0.2,
        "rssi": -9.7
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm matching certain `aircraft` with several `select` statements:

```
jq -r '.aircraft[] | [.lon, .lat, .alt_baro, .seen_pos, .hex ] | select(.[0] > 7) | select(.[0] < 10) | select(.[1] > 49) | select(.[1] < 51) | select(.[2] != null) | select(.[2] != "ground") | select(.[2] < 13000) | @csv' test.json
```

This part works fine (matches the second `aircraft` from the example above):

```
7.385010,49.848068,5250,0.180,"3c4dc5"
```

Now my problem: I'm struggling with doing some math on the fly. I want to subtract `seen_pos` from `now` and use that value in the result. My result should look like

```
7.385010,49.848068,5250,1685613599.699,"3c4dc5"
```

I can't figure out how to access `now` from the outer array. Would you kindly nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remember `.now` before looping (`[]`) deeper.

Start your filter with `.now as $now | ...`

Then in the array you create to keep some data, you can use `$now` as needed:

```
.now as $now 
    | .aircraft[] 
    | [.lon, .lat, .alt_baro, .seen_pos, .hex, ($now - .seen_pos) ] 
    | select(.[0] > 7) | select(.[0] < 10) | select(.[1] > 49) | select(.[1] < 51) | select(.[2] != null) | select(.[2] != "ground") | select(.[2] < 13000) 
    | @csv
```

Output:

```
7.385010,49.848068,5250,0.180,"3c4dc5",1685613599.699
```

As you can test in [this online JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0AEGNO4xIQ_h).

---

An additional tip, consider using `select()` on the object itself, you're now creating a new array even tho `select` will ignore that object, something like this will prevent creating new arrays when it's not needed and stuff like `.lon < 7` is a lot more readable then `.[0] < 7`.

```
.now as $now 
    | .aircraft[] 
    | select(.lon > 7 or .lat < 10)
    | [.lon, .lat, .alt_baro, .seen_pos, .hex, ($now - .seen_pos) ] 
    | @csv
```

Comment: Also great improvement on the select usage in my code. Thank you!